# Strange phantom div named like a <div id="checkdv_1">

Tags: html, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, tailwind-css

[name of it on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6of0a.png),
[that div just staying under my app div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH2Ef.png).
i dont know what is it and seeing this first time on my vue project.

checked extensions and tried to google it to figure it out but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that too. Disabling the Delta free VPN chrome extension helped. Src attribute was a reference to youtube

Comment: thx. yeah, the reason is ext. Just like a tommorow noticed that my youtube acc got a new watched videos even after password swap and disconnect every users

Answer (score 1):

For me,it is generated by the chrome extension Live color picker, a potentional malware.

Comment: yep. that was a reason for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me as if the `<div>` element was given the `id` of "checkdv...". This is used within CSS or JS files to assign styling or call functions. You'll want to check for that `id` name within one of those types of files to see what's happening and why it's there if you don't know what it is.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As @huang kecheng said, was the extencion Live color picker for me too.

It was clear until few days, check your extensions again to see if it dont become a virus.